# Replace `0` instead of the `NULL` SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to replace `0` instead of the `NULL` value.I have tried as shown below.But it's not working.Can you tell me why ?

> SELECT REPLACE(a.[BPOAGE], 'NULL', 0),a.[BPOAttic] FROM
>   [Legacy].[dbo].[MyTables] as a

**Result :**

[image]

Comment: use coalesce in place of null

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`NULL` isn't the same as `'NULL'` (one is the absence of a value, one is the string with letters N, U, L and L), so replacing it like that doesn't work.

Try using the `ISNULL` or `COALESCE` operators.

```
SELECT ISNULL(a.[BPOAGE], 0) AS BPOAGE
  , a.[BPOAttic] 
FROM [Legacy].[dbo].[MyTables] as a
```

Answer (score 1):

And you can also have option to go with `Case Statement`.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN a.[BPOAGE] IS NULL THEN 0
ELSE a.[BPOAGE] END AS BPOAGE, 
a.[BPOAttic] 
FROM [Legacy].[dbo].[MyTables] as a
```

Comment: Good to know about `CASE`.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `COALESCE` to do the same thing as `ISNULL`.

```
SELECT COALESCE(a.[BPOAGE], 0) AS BPOAGE, 
a.[BPOAttic] 
FROM [Legacy].[dbo].[MyTables] as a
```